# UAE visit visa with expired passport number

Tags: visas, passports, dubai, uae, passport-renewals

I need a visa to travel to UAE. My passport will expire soon (June), so today I applied for a new passport and it will be delivered to me on March 17. I need to travel to Dubai on March 18. clearly not enough time to get a visa for the new passport.

Can I send a scan of my old passport to the agency who's getting the visa for me, get a visa with the old passport number on it and then travel with both passports to Dubai? My new passport to satisfy their 6 months validity requirement and the old passport to match the passport number?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, just bring both the old passport with visa and the new valid passport with you.  (Although you'll probably need to give the agency your actual old passport, not just a copy, if it's a visa label and not an electronic one.)

> **I have a standard UAE residency visa, but my passport is due to expire in a couple of months. The visa is valid for another year. How
>   do I go about moving the visa from one passport to another? Is it
>   expensive?**
>
> Usual practice is not to do this, as it is not required. You should
>   apply for a new passport in the usual way and then join the two
>   passports with an elastic band. In fact, many are returned from
>   embassies in this form. You will not be asked any questions when
>   entering or leaving the country, and will incur no additional costs.

That's from a [newspaper](http://www.thenational.ae/lifestyle/personal-finance/keep-old-and-new-passports-attached-to-retain-visa) and is about a residence visa, but the same applies to an ordinary visitor visa as well.

Comment: +1 for confirming it's possible but isn't that exactly what the OP was suggesting?

Comment: Yes, answer updated.

Comment: Thanks. So to confirm, the same applies for electronic visitor visas too right?

Comment: I don't see why not.

Comment: I called the UAE embassy today and they told me that it's NOT even possible for an agency to get the visa if it expires less than 6 months from the beginning of the visa, but if I already have a visa then I can travel with both passports.