# Which passport number should I use?

Tags: visas, passports, bookings

I have 2 passports (one expired with a valid visa and one other passport valid); while booking a ticket, which passport number should I put in?

Comment: See: https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/79636/for-uk-usa-bound-flights-are-details-entered-during-online-check-in-such-as-da

Comment: "one expired with a valid visa" isn't the visa expiring with the passport?

Comment: @Surb, it is quite common for some kind of visa to extend beyond the valid period of the passport. Some countries allow for 10 year multiple entry visa which are given when the passport has a lot less than 10 years left. You use those by showing both old and current passport together.

Comment: Related: https://travel.stackexchange.com/q/36589/37380, https://travel.stackexchange.com/q/24486/37380, https://travel.stackexchange.com/q/39314/37380, https://travel.stackexchange.com/q/49187/37380

Answer (score 32, accepted):

You use the passport number of the valid unexpired passport. The passport is the premier travel document. The expired passport is carried along just to provide evidence of the previously issued valid visa

Reference

Extensive personal experience with similar scenario while visiting different countries.

Comment: ^did you counter any problem by traveling with multiple passports?

Comment: No. Why should I? It is normal.

Comment: I was just wondersing because this is my first time traveling and I'm little bit anxious

Comment: You don't need to be anxious - it is a *very* common occurrence (to the point where people I know have traveled with more than two passports).

Comment: One more question.. i have no experience in travelling. So the passprt is clipped (old one)  but the visa is not. It is basically new. Does that affect?

Comment: The visa is still valid. Clipping of old passports does not change that.